# How to fetch token for OAuth2.0 authorization using apache camel?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, apache-camel, access-token

I am trying to fetch token from a REST end point. This token I need to use to call other APIs for the resources. I am using apache camel to fetch the token after calling the API. However I am getting an error which I am not able to comprehend. I have only REST endpoint as "https://mytokenurl/token" to fetch the token.

```
from("timer://scheduler?period=30s")
        .log("get access token")
        .to("direct:authService");

    from("direct:authService").tracing()
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
        .simple("https://mytokenurl/token") //Which url to give here?
        .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod")
        .simple("POST")
        .setHeader("Content-Type")
        .simple("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .setHeader("Cache-Control")
        .simple("no-cache")
        .setBody()
        .constant("grant_type=client_credentials&scope=${scope}&client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}")
        .to("https://mytokenurl/token") //Error is getting generated here
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .log("response from API: " + body())
       .choice()
        .when().simple("${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == 200")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson,AccessResponseToken.class)
        .setHeader("jwt").simple("${body.access_token}").log("token received")
        .to("direct:toother")
        .otherwise()
        .log("Not Authenticated!!!");
```

The error generated as below -

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route2 at: >>> To[https://myurltoken/token] <<< in route: Route(route2)[From[direct:authService] -> [SetHeader[CamelHt... because of No endpoint could be found for: https:/myurltoken/token, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
    at org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier.doCreateRoute(RouteReifier.java:240) ~[camel-core-reifier-3.18.1.jar:3.18.1]
```

Please let me know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you added [camel-http](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html) dependency to your project?

Comment: @PasiÖsterman - It worked after adding the dependencies. Thanks a lot!